# Is there any alternative to innerHTML with .replace() method?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, dom-manipulation, regexp-replace

I know about the disadvantages of using `innerHTML`. But in my situation, `innerHTML` looks inevitable. Either it is unnecessarily complex or it is not possible(which I don't think so...)

Here is my code:

```js
function identifier(reg, className) {
  const regex = new RegExp(reg, "gi");
  const p2 = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  p2.forEach((ps) => {
    ps.innerHTML = ps.innerHTML.replace(
      regex,
      (match) => `<span class="${className}">${match}</span>`
    );
  });
}
identifier("[^<>]+?:", "identifier");
```

Is there any alternative safer way to do this without using `innerHTML`?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** The `p` element *at beginning* doesn't contain any other tags. It only contains text. But I want to add `spans` to it with the above function. [image: what I am trying to make.]

In this I  am using RegExp with `replace()` method to make all identifiers(eg: Name, Email) a `span` for styling separately. The values like *John Doe* doesn't get styled.

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to do this. You'd have to create new text nodes for the parts of the text surrounding the matches, and then create span nodes for the matches.

Comment: And if there are already HTML tags in the paragraphs, you'll have to navigate through them.

Comment: I think you could do this by iterating through text nodes that aren't inside tags.

Comment: My first thought: Why is this happening in JavaScript at all? This looks like something that should be done when generating the original HTML (i.e. server-side). But apart from that your code is missing too much context to give a good answer. Of course it would be possible to do this without `innerHTML` for any conceivable HTML content, but it would be much easier, if the implementation could be limited to a specific scenario, for example, that the match is always at the beginning of the paragraph not containing any other HTML.

Comment: I have editted the question accordingly @RoToRa .

Comment: _"To see what I am actually planning to do, see this pen (Note that it will change)"_ - and that last part is why you should _not_ provide relevant information via external platforms only. A [mre] of your problem belongs directly into your question.

Comment: @CBroe now I have edited the question and the code is the mre of my problem. The rest of the code are useless in this situation. I have added an image of how it should look. Should I attach the styles here?

Answer (score 0):

With your additional information it's relatively easy:

```
p2.forEach((ps) => {
  // Get text of paragraph removing any HTML
  const text = ps.textContent;

  // Look for colon      
  const colon = text.indexOf(':');
  
  // Skip if there is no colon
  if (colon === -1) {
    return;
  }

  // Delete content of paragraph
  while (ps.lastChild) {
    ps.removeChild(ps.lastChild);
  }

  // Extract texts before (and including) colon and after colon
  const labelText = text.substring(0, colon + 1);
  const otherText = text.substring(colon + 1);

  // Create span with text before colon
  const label = document.createElement('span');
  label.className = className;
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(labelText));

  // Create new text node with text after colon
  const otherTextNode = document.createTextNode(otherText);

  // Add both as new children of the paragraph
  ps.appendChild(label);
  ps.appendChild(otherTextNode);
});
```

It is of course longer than using `innerHTML`, because we are basically rewriting what the regular expression and the HTML parser for the browser is doing.